# algorithm complexity n*(m+n)^2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

i wrote a code as followings:

```
for( i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
    for( j = 0; j < m + i; j++){
        for( k = 0; k < m + i; k++){
            dosomething();
         }
     }
}
```

so the average time complexity was O(n*(m+n/2)*(m+n/2))? what is the worst case big O then? i am confused.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of your algorithm for worst case, best case and average case are all the same.

It is always doing the same number of instructions, for every input of size (n,m).

- The worst case is the maximal possible number of steps you will do for some input `n,m`. This is `O(n*(n+m)^2)`, and can be easily proved by showing that middle and inner loops taking MORE time than by going from `n+m/2` until `n+m`, and since it is in `O(n*(n+m)^2)`, then also the algorithm.
- Similarly - for best case, the same number of steps will have to be taken for a given `n,m`.
- The average case is the expected number of operations which will be done on the input of size `n,m` - but the exact input does not matter here, only size of `n` and `m` - so this will stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Methodically, using Sigma notation would give you the following:

[image]